# Office 365 Management API returning "https://manage.office.com is disabled"

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, office365api

I have a script to retrieve logs from Office 365 Management API. Everything was fine, but now an error appears:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_resource",
  "error_description": "AADSTS500014: Resource 'https://manage.office.com' is disabled.",
  "error_codes": [500014],
  "timestamp": "2019-03-18 15:27:00Z",
  "trace_id": "ff9e93b4-xxx-xxx-xxx-de4d5aa76e00",
  "correlation_id": "0d2275d8-xxx-xxx-xxx-0a5ff2652163"
}
```

I can't find anything about this error in the Office API documentation.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code you're using to call the API?

Comment: You may also want to double check that your App's permissions having been revoked (i.e. you may need to reconsent the application)

Answer (score 4):

The error message says the resource (Office 365 Management API) is not enabled for your tenant for which you are trying to get access token.

To check and enable it- follow the below steps

1. Azure portal > Enterprise application.
2. Search "Office 365 Management API"- Select it
3. Check Properties - if "Enabled for users to sign-in" is not enabled- Enable it.

I hope this will work for you and Users on your tenant will be able to get token for this resource.

Comment: Not sure how I was able to create a subscription in the first place with the same user, but this resolved the issue for me. Thanks.